# Popover doesnt work correctly. Dont show whole string when it is with spaces

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have tried for quiet a long time to implement a popover into a table like this:

```
    public function search (Request $request)
  {

    if($request->ajax())
    {
      $output="";
      $test=DB::table('test')
      ->where('test','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")
      ->orWhere('test','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")
      ->orWhere('test','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")
      ->orWhere('test','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")
      ->orWhere('test','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();

      if($test)
      {

        foreach ($test as $key => $test)
        {

          $output.='<tr>'.
          // '<td>'."<input type= checkbox class=sub_chk data-id=.$test->id.>".'</td>'.
          '<td>'."<button type=button class=btn btn-lg btn-danger data-trigger=hover data-toggle=popover title=$test->testdata-content=$test->info >Hover over me!</button>".'</td>'.
          '<td>'.$test->test.'</td>'.
          '<td>'.$test->test.'</td>'.
          '<td>'.$test->test.'</td>'.
          '<td>'.$test->test.'</td>'.
          '<td>'.$test->test.'</td>'.
          '<td>'.$test->test.'</td>'.
          '<td>'."<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover(); });</script>".'<td>'.
          '</tr>';
        }

        return Response ($output);
      }
    }
  }
```

}

So everything worked correctly as i wanted to be. Know i had this Problem the popover doesnt show the string from the database correctly. In the database the String is with spaces like "This is a test" it would only show "This" when i do it without spaces it would show it like this "Thisisatest". How can i show the whole string from the database with these spaces?

```
'<td>'."<button type=button class=btn btn-lg btn-danger data-trigger=hover data-toggle=popover title=$test->test data-content=$test->test>Hover over me!</button>".'</td>'.
```

Or what do i have to change?

Comment: Are you using some explode function somewhere or some string replace function?

Comment: No everything is as it stands here i have no other functions

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with qutation marks here: data-content='$test->test'